# What is the value of Projection operator, when acting on another projection operator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor

I acknowledge that the metric $$\gamma_{ab}=g_{ab}+n_an_b$$

> However, recently I come to a question that ask what is the value of $\gamma_{ab}\gamma^{ab}$?

I suspect the value to be 3, in the 3+1 Einstein equation. However I have no idea how to get it. Can anyone show me the proof or working?

Comment: That depends on what is $\gamma^{ab}$. If it's understood as inverse of $\gamma_{ab}$ the result is trivial. If indices are raised with $g^{\mu\nu}$ it's different.

Comment: By definition, a projection operator is idempotent $PP=P $.

Comment: The proper form of your projector, is $P= \gamma_a^b$ as it must work from a tensor space to itself. With this choice, it must satisfy $PP=P$ otherwise there is no reason to call it projection operator as I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Just start by writing it out:

$\gamma_{ab}\gamma^{ab} = (g_{ab} + n_an_b) (g^{ab} + n^an^b)$

$= g_{ab}g^{ab} + n_an_bn^an^b + g_{ab}n^an^b + g^{ab}n_an_b$

You can work this out.